# Postfix virtual alias mapped to unix accounts with a catchall for non matches

Tags: email, postfix

I have a postfix mail server set up and mapped to different unix accounts on the server.
I want to be able to accept mail to specific addresses defined in `/etc/postfix/valias` and route to a mapped unix account unless it doesn't exist as an alias then goes to a `catchall` unix users mailbox.

I have been attempting to use regex as a way to accomplish this but it still doesn't work. Everything is being routed to the catchall account regardless of the rules in place.

```
/etc/postfix/valias 

test@example.com                                         unix_acct1
user1@example.com                                        unix_acct2
/user2@example.com$/                                     unix_acct1
/^.*@example.com$/                                        catchall_unix_acct
```

Results of postmap tests that appear to pass correctly

```
 postmap -q "user2@example.com" regexp:/etc/postfix/valias

 postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/valias, line 1: ignoring unrecognized request
 postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/valias, line 2: ignoring unrecognized request
 unix_acct
```

on a non existent email alias on the domain

```
 postmap -q "no-exist@example.com" regexp:/etc/postfix/valias

 postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/valias, line 1: ignoring unrecognized request
 postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/valias, line 2: ignoring unrecognized request
 catchall_unix_acct
```

When I send emails to any address defined as valias or not they all end up in catchall_unix_acct unless I take it out. As mentioned I only want the catchall alias to receive mail if the address its sent to isn't set up as an alias. Is there something I am missing to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the first two lines (those without the `/`) prevent the correct parsing of the third line. Does it work if you delete them? You should replace `/^.*@example.com$/` with `/@example.com$/`. This pattern has lower precedence than `/user2@example.com$/`.

Comment: Thanks @HaukeLaging I made the suggested changes and unfortunately it still has the same behavior, everything goes to the catchall mailbox. I no longer get the first 2 warnings as before though in the postmap checks.

Comment: Is there a typo anywhere? The `postmap -q` output seems to be `unix_acct` but is supposed to be `unix_acct1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 steps to do

modify `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and append this line

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/valias
```

my file `/etc/postfix/valias`

```
/^test@example.com$/                                         debian
/^user1(\+.*)?@example.com$/                                ubuntu$1
/^user2(\+.*)?@example.com$/                                debian$1
/^.*@example.com$/                                          root
```

address on line 2 & line 3 allow the plus extension  .